# Java - How to remove an extra line after "continue" in looping statement

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have tried to make an array table. But, when I add some selection followed by continue statement, it's going to be an extra line. If anyone could give suggestions to me by providing some code techniques?
This is my output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw1nK.jpg)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] table = {{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}, {"FirstClass", "50000", "2%", "No", "No"}, {"SecondClass", "100000", "5%", "Yes", "No"}, {"ThirdClass", "200000", "7%", "Yes", "No"}, {"FourthClass", "300000", "10%", "Yes", "Yes"}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.printf("|%-15s", table[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.print("\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if ("No".equals(table[i][3])) {
                continue; //My Problem
            }
            System.out.printf("|%-15s", table[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: your ``continue`` skips the inner loop, not the outer one. Work with labels to let the ``continue`` skip the outer one.

Comment: Code being too long isnt really something you should probably worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specifiy the outer loop which shall be the jump target for `continue`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] table = {{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}, {"FirstClass", "50000", "2%", "No", "No"}, {"SecondClass", "100000", "5%", "Yes", "No"}, {"ThirdClass", "200000", "7%", "Yes", "No"}, {"FourthClass", "300000", "10%", "Yes", "Yes"}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.printf("|%-15s", table[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.print("\n\n");

    outer:
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if ("No".equals(table[i][3])) {
                continue outer; //note the tag
            }
            System.out.printf("|%-15s", table[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just include the inner loop with the new line print into an `if`, as your outer loop already knows if it will have to print or not.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Just go into the inner loop if you know it would be doing something
    // There´s no need to start it, if it will just skip back to the 
    // outer loop at it´s first iteration even though
    if ("No".equals(table[i][3])) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
           System.out.printf("|%-15s", table[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    } 
}
```